# Cannot get Javascript to un-hide elements by class

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to get certain fields in a form to appear depending on the selection of a dropdown menu. Here's a simplified version of my code, trying to change the display from 'none' to 'block'. What's going wrong?

```js
function selectTrain(trainType) {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (trainType);
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(trainType);
  for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
};
```

```html
<select onchange="selectTrain(this.value)">
      <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a train type</option>
      <option value="lhcs">Loco-hauled carriage set</option>
      <option value="mu">Multiple Unit</option>
      <option value="f">Frieght</option>
    </select>

<!-- Form -->

<form name="myForm">
  <p>Formation Information:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs f">Loco number: <input type="text" id="locoid1"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco number: <input type="text" id="locoid2"></li>
    <li class="mu">Formation number: <input type="text" id="formationid">

    </li>
  </ul>

  <p>Names:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs f">Loco name: <input type="text" id="loconame1"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco name: <input type="text" id="loconame2"></li>
    <li class="mu">Formation name: <input type="text" id="formationname"></li>
    <li class="lhcs mu">Train name: <input type="text" id="trainname"></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Train Operating Company:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco TOC: <input type="text" id="locotoc1"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco TOC: <input type="text" id="locotoc2"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Carriage TOC: <input type="text" id="cartoc"></li>
    <li class="mu">Formation TOC: <input type="text" id="formationtoc"></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Places:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs mu f">Spot or embark point: <input type="text" list="places" id="placeorigin"></li>
    <li class="lhcs mu">Destination: <input type="text" list="places" id="placedest"></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Date and Time:</p>
  <input type="date" id="dateandtime">

  <p>Number of Carriages: </p>
  <input type="number" id="carnum">
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs mu">Carriage 1: <input type="text" id="carid1"></li>
  </ul>

  <button id='submission' type='button' onClick="goForIt()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: For future reference, it can be helpful to check for JavaScript errors your browser's developer console. It's helped me find stubborn errors countless times. For example, in the code snippet above, you'll see the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null", which indicates the missing "test" element.

Comment: @showdev Thank you very much, that's good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to include to you DOM the element with id="test", for example `<div id="test"></div>`. Check out the snippet, it works (i have added this `div` at the bottom of the page):

```js
  function selectTrain(trainType) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (trainType);
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(trainType);
    for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
  };
```

```html
<select onchange="selectTrain(this.value)">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a train type</option>
  <option value="lhcs">Loco-hauled carriage set</option>
  <option value="mu">Multiple Unit</option>
  <option value="f">Frieght</option>
</select>

<!-- Form -->

<form name="myForm">
  <p>Formation Information:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs f">Loco number: <input type="text" id="locoid1"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco number: <input type="text" id="locoid2"></li>
    <li class="mu">Formation number: <input type="text" id="formationid">        

    </li>
  </ul>

  <p>Names:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs f">Loco name: <input type="text" id="loconame1"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco name: <input type="text" id="loconame2"></li>
    <li class="mu">Formation name: <input type="text" id="formationname"></li>
    <li class="lhcs mu">Train name: <input type="text" id="trainname"></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Train Operating Company:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco TOC: <input type="text" id="locotoc1"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Loco TOC: <input type="text" id="locotoc2"></li>
    <li class="lhcs">Carriage TOC: <input type="text" id="cartoc"></li>
    <li class="mu">Formation TOC: <input type="text" id="formationtoc"></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Places:</p>
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs mu f">Spot or embark point: <input type="text" list="places" id="placeorigin"></li>
    <li class="lhcs mu">Destination: <input type="text" list="places" id="placedest"></li>
  </ul>

  <p>Date and Time:</p>
  <input type="date" id="dateandtime">

  <p>Number of Carriages: </p>
  <input type="number" id="carnum">
  <ul>
    <li class="lhcs mu">Carriage 1: <input type="text" id="carid1"></li>
  </ul>

<button id='submission' type='button' onClick="goForIt()">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked (I will accept it as soon as the time limit allows). I may be being thick, but in my code I included that snippet earlier on. It only worked when I transferred it from above the form (and section) <p id="test>Some text</p> to below it.Is there something I'm missing. Thank you so much again.